# Flux through plane surface in hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

Suppose a charge is placed at the centre of a hemispherical surface of radius $R$ then what would be the electric flux passing through the planar surface opposite to the charge in the hemisphere?

I know from gauss law that flux passing through closed surface which contains a charge is $\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$ but here total flux through hemisphere would be half of total flux.

I also know that flux through any other non-closed surface would be $\frac{\Omega}{4\pi} \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$ where $\Omega$ is solid angle .

So I calculated the solid angle for the planar surface . Since solid angle for cone is equal to $2\pi(1-\cos(\theta))$ and $\theta$ here is $\pi/4$ since charge is at center of hemisphere therefore flux comes out to be

$$ \phi= \frac{2\pi(1-\cos(\pi/4))}{4\pi}.\frac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}$$
Is this correct? My answer does not match with the correct answer.

Comment: If you're going to take the brute force approach as you have, you'll need to integrate $\int \vec E\cdot d \vec l$ since $\vec E$ varies over the surface.

Comment: hmm , so would Integral be $\int_0^R \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^2}.2\pi rdr$ ?

Comment: Shouldnt it be ${\epsilon_0}$ in the denominator instead of $2{\epsilon_0}$ ?

Comment: half of the total flux will pass thru hemisphere

Comment: I don't think you can say that half of the total flux will pass through the hemisphere when Q is on the surface. When a point charge is on your surface things will get tricky, and I think the flux should depend on the local curvature of the surface on which your charge is located. Imagine your charge Q is at the center of a sphere with radius $R\sqrt{2}$. Then you can see you need the full $\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$ value.

Comment: Since it's a Point charge , Spherical surface will almost be planer from it's perspective . Like Us and Earth.

Comment: How can you do that ?? Each point in the plane is not at the same distance from the charge, so you can't simply use the equation of solid angle. Do it by integration.

Comment: @Jaswin is the integral I wrote above is correct?

Comment: @Jaswin If you can find the solid angle a given surface's bondary takes up it's a fantastic way to do the problem because of the radial symmetry of a point charge. You can take a certain solid angle from any sphere around a charge and then modify the surface however you want while keeping the boundary fixed and the flux through that surface won't change.

Comment: @BMS you mean $\vec E\cdot\vec{dS}$

Comment: @Sigma, my answer is the same as yours but with an extra factor of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sphere has no electrical properties, I am taking it to just be a mathematical surface. In this case, we are just computing a special case of the electric flux through a disk of radius $R$ from a charge centered on its axis a distance $\ell$ away which is $$ \Phi = \int_0^R E(r) \cos\theta\,dS = \int_0^R dr \frac{Q}{\ell^2 + r^2} (2\pi r)\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{\ell^2+r^2}} $$ This turns out to be $$\Phi = 2\pi Q\left[ 1 - \frac{\ell}{\sqrt{\ell^2+R^2}}\right] $$ Now the only thing special in your case is that since it is on the hemisphere, $\ell\to R$, so $$\Phi = 2\pi Q\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: I just realized you were using $\epsilon_0$ and I did mine in cgs. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The solid angle approach works, it's just when using that formula you need the full charge. The distance from the charge to the edge of the disc formed by your hemisphere is just $R\sqrt{2}$. So draw a sphere of radius $R\sqrt{2}$ around your point charge. The total flux through this sphere will be the full $\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$. Because the electric field is equal at every point on the sphere, the total flux through any part of the sphere will just be equal to the fractional area that surface takes up. This is the solid angle approach. Notice that this approach ignores the surface that Q is located on. The fact that half the flux goes through the hemisphere isn't necessary to solve the problem. Only the geometry created by the hemisphere is relevant.

If you want to do the integral directly, what you wrote is close. But remember that you have $E\cdot dA$ for flux, so you need an extra cosine term to take only the normal component of the electric field. For the flat disc in this problem you have $R=\sqrt{R^2+r^2}\cos\theta$. Additionally, you won't have a constant $R^2$ along the disc, but instead $r^2+R^2$. So your integral would be 
$$ \int_0^R \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0(r^2+R^2)}\frac{2\pi rR}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2}}dr.$$

Comment: It's not $2\pi r^2$ but $2\pi Rr$ in the numerator. (See my answer below.)